# Windows Server: Number of simultaneous connections for IIS and SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, iis, windows-server

The Windows Server version (2008: standard, enterprise, datacenter. 2012: foundation, essentials, datacenter) restricts the maximum number of simultaneous connections for IIS and SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My IIS 8.5 Windows Server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5 shows Maximum concurrent connections limit of 4294967295.

[image]

MS SQL Server 2016/2014/2012 have common concurrent users limit of 32,767.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432(v=sql.130).aspx